# How to setup basic ManageIQ automate environment in Rails console?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-console, manageiq

I used to run some operations in ManageIQ through automate simulation, which is available from UI. 
I'd like to find a way to reproduce these operations from rails console.

For example operations for Instance management - `migrate`, `evacuate` or `relocate` instance.
How do I make it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's the common way to do this:

Set up a basic $evm context in a Rails console

`# rails c`

`# $evm = MiqAeMethodService::MiqAeService.new(MiqAeEngine::MiqAeWorkspaceRuntime.new)`

For example you can find any VM in vmdb and define it into a variable:

`# vm = $evm.vmdb('vm').find('some_id')`

Similar with other objects, e.g.

`flavor = $evm.vmdb('flavor').find(flavor_id)`